# Storyboard Element Layers

Tags: swift3, uistoryboard, xcode8

I have some text on a picture/background, but it is hidden. How do I make elements move back and forth?

Answer (score 3):

If you wish to make an UIView above another while using the storyboard all you have to do it make it above the other element in the document outline.

1. Open on your storyboard
2. Editor -> Show Document Outline (if it already open this would say Hide, but we want to use it)
3. Find the two elements in the list
4. Drag the UIView below the other one. You should be able to see the layers reorder as well.

In your case, it sounds like you should drag the UILabel below the UIImageView.

-- Edit --

I have added a before and after

## Before

[image: Before. Label below image]

## After

[image: After. Label Above image]

Comment: Can you be more specific? I opened my storyboard, I opened view/view standard editor/show document items, but it won't let me drag the items. I also tried opening the mainVC editor on the right, but I can't find it.

Comment: Please see my edit. The editor that needs to be used is the Document Outline.